# Как прочитать массив с файла php

Tags: php

Есть файл с таким массивом

```
return [
  'models'=>[
     'users'

   ],

];
```

Как можно средствами php считать этот массив?

Comment: `$array = require_once 'array.php'`. Подробности см. [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае для PHP 5.4 и выше

```
$array = include 'имя файла с массивом.php';
```

---

Опоздал на 30 сек :)

Comment: А как в более старых версиях?

Comment: Аналогично, но запись массива в файле должна быть через array.

Comment: return array (
  'models'=> array (
     'users'

   ),

);